Open developer options programmatically on Samsung Android 14
In my Android app, I have a button that appears only when the developer menu is enabled by the user. This button uses intent to open the developer menu (Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS). It was working fine with any vendor\android version, but recently I discovered that this button doesn't open the developer menu on Samsung with One UI 6.1 + Android 14 (SM A346E), it shows toast with text "Turn on Developer options first" (of course it already turned on).
I tried similar apps with a button to the dev menu (like Shizuku) on that device, and the result was the same, so the problem is not in my code.
It looks like this behaviour is a new Samsung security feature. If anyone has encountered this problem and found a solution, please share.

Solved: looks like this problem exists only on model SM-A346E Android 14. Yesterday I have tested it on other Samsung models with Android 14 and had no mentioned problem.I'll wait for a solution from Samsung.

I bet you have to wait for OS update for this model... msg doesn't make sense, maybe it should prompt about "usb debugging" turned on, maybe this could be called "security feature" (still looks like a bug, at least in translation/text). btw. just checked that, from doc: As of Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 this action is a required part of the platform., so it very should work

Yep, looks like this problem exists only on model SM-A346E Android 14. Yesterday I have tested it on other Samsung models with Android 14 and had no mentioned problem.

I'm also encountering this issue on a different Samsung device running Android 14. Were you able to solve this issue?

I happen to have that exact same phone, and OS
https://i.sstatic.net/51EpXGjH.png
However, I don't encounter any issue with the process
https://i.sstatic.net/f53TUaT6.gif

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
